# Selenium IDE Webscraping - How do I create an Array (Or Multiple outputs)

Tags: regex, selenium, selenium-ide

I have just got to grips with how to do Multiple "individual" Selenium codesnippets for webscraping individual values, and I'm happy I can extend this further.

I previously used a piece of software called Travelsure which used Regex scraping, and if it found multiple values, it would place them all in an array

So one of my Travelsure Scrapes was

```
<div(.*?)>
```

This outputted (The "()" is the bit that is saved), every single div and the contents inside the div tag. This was outputted as a CSV

On Selenium, if I ask it to look at a large range, it **concatenates** it all because it assumes I want just ONE item, example below

```
storeText | css=h1.header-style-e.color-q | tree
```

I want it to give me an output of 8 values in a CSV for example:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

Instead of

```
abcdefgh
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Perhaps have a browse through [ask], to avoid having your questions closed.

Comment: I've re-edited it. It made sense to me before - Tried to use more code examples.